# Moving a picture that is inside a PictureBox to another PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

How can I move a picture that is inside a picturebox to another picturebox?

I want to use it for moving the pieces of chess game. I have a took picturebox for each place, so I have 64 pictureboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can just assign the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) displayed in one picture box to another picture box.** If you then want to remove the image from the original picture box (so that it is not displayed twice), you can set its `Image` property to `null` (or, of course, you can assign any other image of your choice). Like so:

```
//Assign the image in one picture box to another picture box
mySecondPicBox.Image = myFirstPicBox.Image;

//Clear the image from the original picture box
myFirstPicBox.Image = null;
```

If you want to *swap* the images displayed in two picture boxes, you need to temporarily store one of the picture objects in a variable. So you can use very similar code, with a slight modification:

```
//Temporarily store the picture currently displayed in the second picture box
Image secondImage = mySecondPicBox.Image;

//Assign the image from the first picture box to the second picture box
mySecondPicBox.Image = myFirstPicBox.Image;

//Assign the image from the second picture box to the first picture box
myFirstPicBox.Image = secondImage;
```