# moving picture in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, chess

hi friends
 im making a simple chess game.and i want to know how can i move between pictureboxes?i made 64 pictureboxes(for each place one picturebox) and for example i want to move the king piece that is in picturebox2 in the picturebox that is on top of the picturebox2.thanks for your help

for example like this:

```
 picturebox2.image=picturebox.image.up///move the image in picturebox into the picture box that is on top of the picturebox2
```

is it possible?

Comment: Check the answer given in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243162/moving-a-picture-that-is-inside-a-picturebox-to-another-picturebox

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243162/moving-a-picture-that-is-inside-a-picturebox-to-another-picturebox

Comment: @Cody Gray:this is different question.i dont want to manually move picture,i want it does automatic

Comment: its my question,and its different

Comment: by automatic, do you mean it should happen as a result of some event? Like the user clicks some button and then this moving takes place?

Comment: You might want to explain your problem a bit more: do you want to know how to set the image of picturebox1 to the image of picturebox2, OR is the question about how to locate the picturebox that's above the first one?

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with Chess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is "how to locate the field that's above the current field":

You need to store your pictureBoxes not (just) as picturebox1 to pictureBox64, but (also) as a two-dimensional array: `PictureBox[,] grid = new PictureBox[8,8];`. (*)

Then you need to find out where that 'current' field is in the grid. From there it's simple to calculate where the 'next' field would be (y=y+1). Watch out that you don't go over the edge of the field.

(*) Although you might want to remember more per field than just the picturebox, such as what piece (if any) occupies that field?

Comment: thanks god t,h,at one person understood what i mean,[7,7] shouldnt be instead of [8,8]?can you help me a little that how can i take current place?thanks so much

Comment: @arash: there are 8 fields to a side (so [8,8] is correct), numbered (in code) from 0 to 7.