# swap pictureboxes with each other

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I'm making a Bejeweled game and i'm getting some isseus.
The problem that i am working on now is that when i have selected 2 diamonds they need to swap positions.

I am making pictureboxes with randomly images inside of them(1 to 7 colors).
when i know the color i am making a picturebox for it

```
switch (diamant)
{
  case "1":
    dia = new Diamant(this, "Rood", XWaarde, YWaarde, new Point(XWaarde, YWaarde));
    break;
  case "2":
    dia = new Diamant(this, "Groen", XWaarde, YWaarde, new Point(XWaarde, YWaarde));
    break;
  case "3":
    dia = new Diamant(this, "Geel", XWaarde, YWaarde, new Point(XWaarde, YWaarde));
    break;
  case "4":
    dia = new Diamant(this, "Paars", XWaarde, YWaarde, new Point(XWaarde, YWaarde));
    break;
  case "5":
    dia = new Diamant(this, "Wit", XWaarde, YWaarde, new Point(XWaarde, YWaarde));
    break;
  case "6":
    dia = new Diamant(this, "Oranje", XWaarde, YWaarde, new Point(XWaarde, YWaarde));
    break;
  case "7":
    dia = new Diamant(this, "Blauw", XWaarde, YWaarde, new Point(XWaarde, YWaarde));
    break;
}
```

I save them in a list and from there i want to change them from position i know which x and y position they both have.
But dont know how i need to start this swapping.

Somebody can give me a idea to swap them.

or is it better to make 64 (8 X 8) pictureboxes and than fill them with a color?

kind regards,

Maikel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Diamant tmp = firstDiamant;
firstDiamant = secondDiamnt;
secondDiamnt = tmp;
```

Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Okay..

```
        Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
        pictureBox2.Image = tmp;
```

Comment: yes u understand my question but the problem is how i can solve this issue i already tryed something like what u said but it need to be drawn again on the screen and thats the major issue where it is giving problems

Comment: @user1810196 so you are trying to swap the pictures in two different pictureboxes?

Comment: found a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243162/moving-a-picture-that-is-inside-a-picturebox-to-another-picturebox i am going to try that but that is going to take some days if it isnt working i will come back.

but thanks anyways for the fast response

Comment: Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox2.Image;
            pictureBox2.Image = tmp;

Comment: Sir u gave me great example and ive been trying to implement them all day the problem that i recent found is that ive got 64 pictureboxes

How can i say to my program picturebox1 (in your example) is the chosen picturebox 55 and need to swap with picturebox2 (in your example) that is picturebox 54?